# Not able to access BouncyCastle jar from application jar

Tags: bouncycastle

I have made jar file for my application. One of the class of my application uses BouncyCastleProvider class of BC jar.

I have created one folder "lib" in the same parent folder where my application jar is residing.

I have changed my machine CLASSPATH to point to this new lib folder. But when I run my application it gives me classnotfound exception.

But if I copy this BC jar file to my jre/lib/ext then everything works fine.

Can anybody tell me what I need to do to access BC jar file from my lib directory?

Thanks in Advance,
Jenish

Answer (score 0):

Your JAR file must have its MANIFEST.MF file set to declare the classpath for the JAR.#

Extract from the [Sun Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) below, in your case you just need to make the Class-Path directive point to your lib directory, presumably

```
Class-Path: lib/BouncyCastle.jar
```

> We want to load classes in MyUtils.jar
>   into the class path for use in
>   MyJar.jar. These two JAR files are in
>   the same directory.
>
> We first create a text file named
>   Manifest.txt with the following
>   contents:
>
> ```
> Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
>
> Warning : The text file must end with a new line or carriage return.
> ```
>
> The last line will not be parsed
>   properly if it does not end with a new
>   line or carriage return.
>
> We then create a JAR file named
>   MyJar.jar by entering the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class
> ```
>
> This creates the JAR file with a
>   manifest with the following contents:
>
> ```
> Manifest-Version: 1.0
> Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
> Created-By: 1.6.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
> ```
>
> The classes in MyUtils.jar are now
>   loaded into the class path when you
>   run MyJar.jar.